# How to show C[0,1] is not closed in $L^2$?

Tags: real-analysis

How to show M=C[0,1] is not closed in $L^2$?

My idea is to we pick up a sequence $f_n \in M$, then suppose $f_n$ is Cauchy in $L^2$. We need to show that $\lim f_n = f \notin M$.

My attempt is g(x)=1, x irrational; = 0 if x is rational. Then g=h almost everywhere, where h(x)=1. h is in C[0,1]. Do I have $\lim g =h$?

Comment: Consider $f(x)=\mathbb{1}_{(1/2,1]}$ and approximate in by sequences in $C[0,1]$. For example, for $n\geq 3$ consider function that is $0$ in $[0,1/2-1/n]$,  1 in $[1/2,1]$, and linear in $[1/2-1/n,1/2]$

Answer (score 2):

The main technical difficulty here is that $C([0,1])$ does not embed into $L^2$ as functions, it embeds as equivalence classes. This means that you not only need to construct a sequence that converges in $L^2$ norm to something discontinuous, you need to show that the limiting function can't be modified on a null set to be continuous. This means your idea does not work, because $f_n(x) \equiv 1$ *also* converges in $L^2$ norm to $f \equiv 1$, as well as to the indicator of the irrationals.

That being said, a good way to proceed is to approximate a function with a jump discontinuity by continuous functions.